# UITextField not getting keyboard input

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, ios6

I'm having troubles entering text into an UITextField under a [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/barrettj/SVProgressHUD) (Basically an UIView with a full-screen transparent UIWindow and some UIView subviews showing text and a custom-drawn progress bar).

My problem is that the UITextField displays the blinking cursor and the keyboard shows, but when I tap a key, nothing is entered into the text field.
I only see that the cursor's blinking interrupts just like normal.
Interestingly enough, the back (delete) key works (it really deletes the last letter in the UITextView), but not any other key.

I'm using iOS 6.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:
The same UITextField works fine when there's no SVProgressHUD displayed. This makes me think it has something to do with the first responder, but I have already tried calling `resignFirstResponder` on every window and subview of the SVProgressHUD and it still does not work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I finally found the problem:
SVProgressHUD calls `makeKeyAndVisible` when it's initialized, because it wants to receive keyboard notifications for repositioning. I looked up what the "Key Window" actually is and found out:

> ...The key window responds to user input...

Now, as the UIWindow of the SVProgressHUD was the keyWindow, my other window, which contained the UITextField did not get the user input.

I finally call `makeKeyWindow` on the AppDelegate's window and everything is working fine.

I hope this helps anyone with similar problems.

Comment: can we use  makeKeyWindow and makeKeyAndVisible both.is that any sense or use

Comment: I have no idea why this answer doesn't have a few hundred upvotes by now. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know why I bother debugging problems like this anymore when StackOverflow always comes through. Thanks!

Comment: In my case the opposite was true. My UITextField was within a different window than the AppDelegate, but an alert brought the focus back to the AppDelegate. performing a `makeKeyWindow` on the correct UIWindow object fixed it for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: In my case, I grab the key window for custom popups and progress info.  in iOS 6, I have to explicitly reset the makeKeyWindow to get keyboard input. ICK.

Comment: Amazing, worked like a charm, thank you, was stuck for days with this issue.

Comment: I had this same problem, difference was that my UITextField was a subview of regular UITableViewCell. Problem was that I was showing UIAlertView from app delegate's method - (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. For a reason, iOS after dismissing alert view did not set key window to app's window. This problem shows in iOS 6.1.x only. In iOS 6.0 or iOS 7 it's OK.

Comment: Saved my day. and agree with Steve, it should have more than a hundred right now.

Answer (score 4):

Call `resignFirstResponder()` to dismiss the keyboard before showing `SVProgressHUD`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you implemented the method....

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

...to filter out any unwanted characters?  If so, perhaps it's being a little overzealous with the filtering?

Comment: I don't use shouldChangeCharactersInRange (It's an UITextField actually. Sorry, I've now updated my question ) for the text field.
Moreover, the same UITextField works fine when there's no SVProgressHUD displayed above. Thanks for your answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

For me this is worked.

I did changes in my textfield delegate method then it worked.

```
if ([textField isEqual:selectBankName])
{
   return No;
}
else if ([textField isEqual:enterAmountTextfield])
{
    return YES;
}

return NO;
}
```

1. set delegate for textfield
2. Make sure textfield userInteraction is Enabled.And
3. Finally Please check your textfield delegate method.