# In Textfield, cant type anything with ios 6 and xcode 4.5 while working in ios 5 perfectly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am stuck in a problem which is related to ios 6. i have login view having two fields named  username and password. after entering some text in both , user can login. after doing some task pressed a logout button and comes out at login view again but this time user cant type anything in the textfield. Its working in ios 5 but in ios 6 its cant. For finding the solution i have made again my app with xcode 4.5 just copied all code but all viewcontrollers are new. but i could not solved it.

I have done it in app delegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   

     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions

       {

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        [self.window setRootViewController:_navController];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[

        UIImage imageNamed: @"top_barBG.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

       _navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

        navimage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

       navimage.frame = CGRectMake(100, 25, 118, 32);

       navimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];


      [_navController.view addSubview:navimage];



    return YES;
```

}

One Problem is more that is in inner view controllers where all i have textfields cant type anything while cursor is present with keyboard and  resignFirstResponder is not working.

Please guys help me. it will be a great help.

Comment: Put together a demo project that shows the problem, put it on DropBox or equiv so we can download it and look at the code. We don't need your whole app just the login code.

Comment: I have found the solution .It was happening because of SVProgressHud ActivityIndicator.

Comment: Paste that into the answer field, and when you can select it as the answer. It will do you good too as your stats will improve in answered questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654085/uitextfield-not-getting-keyboard-input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem of text fields not working on iOS 6 comes from a window, from a xib, which is not set :

Take your first ViewController, which defines your rootviewcontroller. His xib is necessarily associated to a window : set the property "visible a launch" at true for this window.

Comment: If I can venture an educated guess; I'd say it has something to do with the responder chain not being setup correctly.