# UITextField won't becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm having a problem getting a textfield to accept the becomeFirstResponder directive.

I'm providing a custom mechanism to create a title in the navigation bar. I have another viewcontroller that is successfully using this same technique. On viewDidAppear I fire off:

```
- (void)addTitleTextField
{
    CGRect textFrame = self.parentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    textFrame.size.width = 300.0;
    textFrame.origin.y = (768.0 - 300.0)/2;
    textFrame.size.height = 30.0;
    textFrame.origin.x = 7.0;
    self.titleTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFrame];
    self.titleTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"New Multiple Choice Quiz", @"New Multiple Choice Quiz");
    self.titleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.titleTextField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    self.titleTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.titleTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.titleTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.titleTextField.delegate = self;
    [self.titleTextField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    self.titleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    [self.titleTextField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    self.activeTextField = self.titleTextField;
    self.parentViewController.navigationItem.titleView = self.titleTextField;
    [self.titleTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

self.titleTextField will allow me to set the text value, but if you check using canBecomeFirstResponder it returns NO. As you can see I am setting this on the parentViewController. I've tried using a delegate to attempt to get the parentViewController to set it. When I do the delegate and check whether the textField canBecomeFirstResponder it returns YES, but I'm still unable to make it accept the firstResponder order. Any ideas? The Docs say "A responder object only becomes the first responder if the current responder can resign first-responder status (canResignFirstResponder) and the new responder can become first responder".

Comment: Does the keyboard pop up when you touch the field?

Comment: Have you added the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to your class definitions? Have you set `textfield.delegate = self;`?

Comment: You should also add the textfield to your view, with `addSubView:`

Comment: @sangony Yes the keyboard pops up.

Comment: @Marcel Yes you can see the delegate is assigned in that code, and the UITextFieldDelegate has been added.

Comment: @Marcel Oops sorry I mixed you up with ott. The view is being added to the UINavigationBar without a problem. So, the view gets added and receives text input. Everything is working; it just won't accept firstresponder.

Comment: @ott-- please see my comment wrongly addressed to Marcel above.

Comment: Can you add the code of your `viewDidAppear`, if it's beyond 2000 lines?

Comment: What if you set self.navigationItem.titleBar to be your titleTextField? That seems to be working for me locally.

Comment: The answer below worked in my case, but someone else who searches for this will find your many great suggestions and one of your suggestions will probably solve their issue. So, thanx for all your suggestions. I'm grateful.

Comment: @Yoga My bad. Thanx for taking a moment to remind me!

Comment: I have answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654085/uitextfield-not-getting-keyboard-input/31980256#31980256
 
Check if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Are you telling the UITextField to become selector on a background thread?**

```
[textField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil 
  waitUntilDone:YES];
```

**Rationale**: Calling UIKit methods (ie updating the view) on a method other than the main thread won't work. . this could be happening. (It is not clear where the addTitleTextField method is being called from).

**Is there another first responder that needs some time to resign?**

```
[textField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

**Rationale**: If another field is hanging onto first responder (or in the process of resigning it), it will give it time to clean up an resign, by waiting until the next run-loop. . . . . usually the next run-loop will be enough time for the previous responder to clean up, or you could try a short delay like 0.05.

Comment: Brilliant! Why would this work exactly? I don't think it has to do with another tread.

Comment: Why not performSelectorOnMainThread? If the problem is that the code is running on a background thread I would think you'd want to do that...

Comment: @JasperBlues thanx for fleshing out the reply. In my case I don't think it's a threading issue. Probably something hasn't resigned first responder.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add textField to view hierarchy:

```
v.addSubview(textField)
```

Comment: How would he see the TextView if not in the view hierarchy?

Comment: `textField.superview != nil` means the textField is in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to do is to **make sure the textField is enabled** (check Interface Builder, then any disabling you might do through code).

I spent almost an hour trying to figure out what the problem was: I got a workaround by subclassing UITextField and overriding `canBecomeFirstResponder` to always `return true`. This forced it to finally show keyboard and edit the textField, but I noticed I couldn't tap/select/copy/paste the textField. User Interaction was enabled, and then I finally saw the Enabled not being checked...I blame Apple for not displaying any visual cue when a piece of UI is disabled (like the do with Hidden) lol