# becomeFirstResponder doesn't work if previously followed by resignFirstResponder for another text field

Tags: ios, ios8

I have two text fields, when the user has finished entering text for the first one I want to move on to the next one, hence I have code like this:

```
    [self.firstTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    ...

- (void) onUserClickingDoneEnteringPhoneNumberButton
{
    ....
    [self.firstTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.secondTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

However this does not work, the resignFirstResponder is making the keyboard go away but it is then not reappearing for secondTextField.

NOTE: having only [self.secondTextField becomeFirstResponder]; present results in nothing happening.

onUserClickingDoneEnteringPhoneNumberButton is being used because the keypad type for firstTextField is UIKeyboardTypePhonePad, hence a done button has been added as an accessoryView to the keypad.

No, its not a problem with the delegate not being set for secondTextField - I can make the keypad appear for secondTextField if it has not first been set for firstTextField.

Comment: This question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003057/uitextfield-wont-becomefirstresponder may help.

Comment: The solutions there didn't work, but  based on it I did the following which did: [self.firstTextField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: Great! I'm glad the link helped.