# Not able to input text by keyboard after UIImagePickerController is dismiss.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I develop my application in `cocos2D`.

And i used custom `UIView` which has 2 `UITextField` and 1 `UITextView` and also has functionality of get photo.

In My application I use `UIImagePickerController` to take image from camera/Library. All of the functionality are works properly but after when I choose photo from camera/Library and then dismiss my `imagePicker` then i am not able to enter text again in `UITextField`.

I also look this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654085/uitextfield-not-getting-keyboard-input), and follow them.

**My Relevant code is:**

```
#pragma Mark -
#pragma Mark - ActionSheet Delegate Methods

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.delegate=self;
    imgPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    imgPicker.allowsEditing=YES;

    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        isVideoTakenFromCamera = YES;
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
            imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        else
            imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }
    else if (buttonIndex==1)
    {
        isVideoTakenFromCamera = NO;
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }


    [[XPSModal sharedInstance] hideWindow]; // it is my custom UIView.
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
   // [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] makeKeyWindow]; i alsos put here this code but it is not works for me.
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UIImagePickerController Delegate Method

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

   UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   img = [self resizeImage:img];
   [self.btnTakePhoto setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   [[XPSModal sharedInstance] showWindow]; // it is my custom UIView.
   [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] makeKeyWindow];
}
```

Problem is occurs when i select photo from library/camera. other wise keyboard is work properly.

Comment: May b your keyboard is overlapped by a window.. try to debug crefully using backGround color property of UIWindow

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Declare this `UIImagePickerController  *imagePicker;`  as a global then follow this code..




-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

    {

        if(buttonIndex==1)
        {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        } else if(buttonIndex==2) {
            if ( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] || [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

            }

        }


    }
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        [imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        _profilePicImgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_profilePicImgView.image, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }
```