# UITextField Becomes First Responder, but keyboard not displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

This is a problem I'm only seeing on iPhone 5 models running 8.1 or greater.

I make a textfield first responder, and it does become first responder (returns true) and its delegate is receiving the expected messages, but the keyboard does not appear.  Has anyone observed anything like this?

Comment: are you  using simulator?

Comment: if you are using simulator press CMD + k to toggle the keyboard...

Comment: To add to that, the option is in Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard

Comment: what's with the down vote?  No, this is observed with actual devices by various users in the field.  All have 5s or 5c phones.  It's not observed on any other devices.

Comment: Possible reason: main window has not yet been made "key". See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654085/uitextfield-not-getting-keyboard-input

Answer (score 0):

Check out this if you are working on simulator.

Just click on simulator and then follow this screenshot.

[image: Please checkout this screen shot if you are working on simulator]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: well I haven't face this kind of problem in device yet.. I am running iOS 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I can only say, try to make the textfiled first responder on main thread, if you are not doing already. If this is not the case, i do not see any other reason.